# How can I drag an image in Listview rows

Tags: android, listview

I want to do something in a listview as follows:
In any row in the listView will be an image. This image can be moved by dragging them to other rows. For example: image position 3. Image dragged 4, 5 and 6 rows. I have to change the background color for 4, 5 and 6 position. How can I drag the image and how can I change the row background color?

Answer (score 0):

The above is a easy task. I have seen many links regarding this in stack overflow itself . I am adding stackoverflow link and github link(of the project).

GitHub

[Project containing demo of drag and drop in the listview](https://github.com/aleung/tasks365/blob/415dc29d1c8d66f1d696b17c0b934002b8f02565/tasks365/src/leoliang/tasks365/DraggableListView.java)

stackoverflow link

[android scroll while drag & drop](https://www.google.co.in/#q=How+to+drag+image+across+list+view+in+android)

[Android Reordering ListView items with drag and drop [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853863/android-reordering-listview-items-with-drag-and-drop)

[drag and drop imageview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368791/drag-and-drop-imageview-android)