# App is FC if the user presses too much to left or right

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I have the following XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llColorSpect"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/color_scheme_height"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/colorspect"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/seek_bar_margin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvBGColor" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlColorSpect"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivSquare"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/title_text_pad"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/title_text_pad"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/esquare" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My partial Java code:

```
View.OnTouchListener llTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int)x,(int) y);

        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                Log.i("COORDINATES","Touch coordinates : x" + String.valueOf(x) + "y" + String.valueOf(y));
                ivTouch.setX(x);
                ivTouch.setY(y);
                int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
                int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
                int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
                Log.d("Colors","R:" +redValue +" G:" +greenValue+" B:" + blueValue);
                sbRed.setProgress(redValue);
                sbGreen.setProgress(greenValue);
                sbBlue.setProgress(blueValue);
                dispHVal();
            break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{
                Log.i("COORDINATES","Touch coordinates : x" + String.valueOf(x) + "y" + String.valueOf(y));
                ivTouch.setX(x);
                ivTouch.setY(y);
                int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
                int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
                int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
                Log.d("Colors","R:" +redValue +" G:" +greenValue+" B:" + blueValue);
                sbRed.setProgress(redValue);
                sbGreen.setProgress(greenValue);
                sbBlue.setProgress(blueValue);
                dispHVal();
            break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

The issue I am coming across.

1. While pressing on the layout to get the coordinate on certain part of it (If I press/drag all the way to the left or to the right), my app FC. I am adding the LogCat below:

> 01-25 01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-25 01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x must be < bitmap.width() 01-25
>   01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):    at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelAccess(Bitmap.java:1155) 01-25
>   01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):    at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixel(Bitmap.java:1107) 01-25 01:13:21.059:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13345):  at
>   com.test.testing.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:98) 01-25
>   01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):    at
>   android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7241) 01-25
>   01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
>   01-25 01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903) 01-25
>   01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
>   01-25 01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875) 01-25
>   01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
>   01-25 01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875) 01-25
>   01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
>   01-25 01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875) 01-25
>   01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
>   01-25 01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875) 01-25
>   01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
>   01-25 01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
>   01-25 01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):  at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410) 01-25
>   01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
>   01-25 01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):  at
>   android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426) 01-25
>   01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
>   01-25 01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
>   01-25 01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
>   01-25 01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
>   01-25 01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
>   01-25 01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):  at
>   android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
>   01-25 01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):  at
>   android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method) 01-25
>   01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):    at
>   android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125) 01-25
>   01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124) 01-25 01:13:21.059:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13345):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195) 01-25
>   01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-25
>   01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 01-25 01:13:21.059:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13345):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
>   01-25 01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562) 01-25
>   01:13:21.059: E/AndroidRuntime(13345):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I want to allow the user to be able to drag all the way to the left, top, right, and bottom. How do I modify the above code to achieve that? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move your x and y logging to before you access the bitmap to see what values are being returned.
2. Per the stacktrace, don't call getPixel with values x and y which exceed the dimensions of your bitmap.