# Why does layout, set to match_parent, displays a 0 width

Tags: android, xml, android-bitmap

I have the following code:

```
llColors = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llColorSpect);
    llColors.setOnTouchListener(llTouch);

    width = llColors.getWidth();
    height = llColors.getHeight();

    Log.i("LAYOUT WIDTH", "width" +width); //shows 0
    Log.i("LAYOUT HEIGHT", "height" +h); //shows the correct height
```

What makes me confused is why is the `LAYOUT WIDTH` is 0. In the XML, I set the layout width to `match_parent` and height to `wrap_content`.

How do I take the `Bitmap` that I am decoding below and fill in the layout above width fill_parent? Do I use LayoutParams?

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.palette2);
```

The XML code is this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llColorSpect"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/palette2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
</LinearLayout>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is lehman term is, take the layout and fill it with a background image and use the pixel to get X and Y coordinate.

Comment: I know that the measurements resolve to zero when the view has not yet been loaded. Have you tried setting it using llColors.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

Comment: @Sunil How do I set the bitmap to match the layout as well? I will test out your code tonight. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `getWidth()` too early. The UI has not been sized and laid out on the screen yet.

Try getting size after overriding the `onWindowFocusChanged()` function:

```
@Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  //Here you can get the size!
 }
```

Have a look at this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/pTNy4cRo7wE)

If you want your bitmap to match parent height and width you can use this:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I've noticed that it's sometimes unpredictable - you can have hooks to make sure that the view is loaded but before it has, I have seen that it is quite unpredictable. Never looked too much into it though.

Comment: This was an extended question from this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347431/app-is-fc-if-the-user-presses-too-much-to-left-or-right. Do you think if I modify the code like the one posted here should work?

Comment: I need to set the background of the Layout :/

Comment: I'm not able to understand what you are trying to accomplish. If you want your bitmap to be the background of your layout, you can simply call setBackgroundResource() but in that case the image(if larger than layout) will not maintain the aspect ratio and you won't be able to do any calculations based on bitmap pixels.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the `width` being 0, the `layout` may not be finished being drawn yet. I used `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to know when it had been drawn. Here is a bit of code how I have done it to make my `layout` a `Bitmap` so I could print it. A little different but same concept.

```
@Override 
public void onGlobalLayout() 
{
    String path = null;
        try {
            path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().toString();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path + "/testPrint" + "0" + ".png");
            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(root.getDrawingCache(), 0, 0, 
                    root.getWidth(), root.getHeight());                             
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);                
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

where `root` is the inflated `layout` that I needed to get the `width` of.

and you can set the `listener` with something like

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener((OnGlobalLayoutListener) root.getContext());
```

[OnGlobalLayoutListener Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html)

Comment: What I am pretty much looking to do is use the bitmap inside the layout and onDrag get the X and Y coordinate to convert to RGB values.